# Read the text of a Windows console application using Python

Tags: python, windows, console

I want to use Python to automate an old application running on an independent Windows console. I want to continue using the application on the console normally, writing commands and getting results, etc. From time to time I want to capture the console text from the Python application. I have no problem to send commands to the console application from my Python program. However, it seems *impossible* to read the text that appears in the console window. I am using subprocess to do it, for example:

```
from subprocess import Popen, CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE, PIPE

newp = Popen(["oldapp.exe"], creationflags=CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE, stdout = None)

while True:
    s = newp.stdout.readline()
    if not s:
        break
    print s,
```

When I use `stdout = None`, I can open the oldapp.exe in and independent console and use it normally but I can not read the console text from python.

When I use `stdout = PIPE`, the oldapp.exe seems to open in and independent console but don't appear any text on this console. But on this case *I can read the console text* from python!

Is there any way to read the console text from the python application AND be able to interact with the console application normally?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Only thing that comes to my mind is to spawn your oldapp exe without console and set stdin of your process to also be a PIPE, then you can interact with your old application purely from Python.

Comment: Maybe something like `tee` could help you (should be available via gnuwin32). Or use `threading` and manage program output and user input in python. Have you seen [subprocess.popen.communicate()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate) ?